# How can I get daily login user number?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, period

I have a logged_log table, the table have username, login_time and logout_time column.
I need to count daily login user.

Table structure:

| column name | type |
| --- | --- |
| username | varchar(32) |
| login_time | datetime |
| logout_time | datetime nullable |

sample data:

| username | login_time | logout_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ddd | 2023-01-05 23:10:00 | null |
| aaa | 2023-01-06 23:10:00 | 2023-01-06 23:59:00 |
| bbb | 2023-01-06 23:35:00 | 2023-01-07 03:00:00 |
| ccc | 2023-01-07 13:35:00 | 2023-01-07 14:00:00 |
| ccc | 2023-01-07 18:35:00 | 2023-01-07 19:00:00 |
| aaa | 2023-01-08 13:35:00 | 2023-01-09 14:00:00 |
| bbb | 2023-01-09 13:35:00 | null |
| ccc | 2023-01-09 14:35:00 | 2023-01-10 14:00:00 |
| aaa | 2023-01-10 13:35:00 | null |

expected results:

| date | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 |
| 2023-01-06 | 3 |
| 2023-01-07 | 3 |
| 2023-01-08 | 2 |
| 2023-01-09 | 4 |
| 2023-01-10 | 4 |

I have try to use case to replace the null logout on logged_log part,
then create temp table of day list on date_period part,
but when join the table to get result, only has first day and total of all days users.

```
SELECT
   daily_logged_log.date, count( daily_logged_log.username )
FROM (
   SELECT
      date_period.date, logged_log.username
   FROM (
      SELECT curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as date
      FROM (SELECT 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
      cross join (SELECT 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
      cross join (SELECT 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
      cross join (SELECT 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
   ) as date_period
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 
         username, 
         DATE( login_time ) as login_at,
         CASE
            WHEN logout_time IS NULL
            THEN DATE( NOW() )
            ELSE DATE( logout_time )
            END
         as logout_at
      FROM logged_log
      WHERE DATE( login_time ) <= '2023-01-09'
      AND CASE
            WHEN logout_time IS NULL
            THEN DATE( NOW() )
            ELSE DATE( logout_time )
            END >= '2023-01-07'
   ) as logged_log
   ON date_period.date BETWEEN logged_log.login_at AND logged_log.logout_at
   WHERE date_period.date BETWEEN '2023-01-07' AND '2023-01-09'
   GROUP BY date_period.date, logged_log.username
) as daily_logged_log
```

Comment: Table structure, sample data, and expected results would help ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) would be especially welcome). Also which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @danblack mysql 5.0

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `total` column in the expected output ?  What does it represent,? I thought it was the total login number for all users who initiated the login on a particular day but the expected output values shows otherwise.

Comment: @blabla_bingo 2023-01-07 has ddd, bbb and ccc. 2023-01-08 has ddd and aaa. 2023-01-09 has ddd, aaa, bbb and ccc.

Comment: @blabla_bingo When login time before or equal to the count date and the logout time after or equal to the count date the user is count has login. And then, if login time before or equal to the count date and logout time is null, the user is online, also count the user has login on count date. So, The total is count the count date how many unique user has login

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken, it aims to count the number of ONLINE unique users for each day. If so, there are 3 records missing from the expected output. For 2023-01-05,it would be ddd; For 2023-01-06,it would be ddd,aaa,bbb. For 2023-01-10, it would be ddd,bbb,aaa. Is that right ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo Yes, but 2023-01-10 is ddd, bbb, ccc, aaa, because the ccc logout time is 2023-01-10 14:00:00. And I want to get the date range from 2023-01-07 to 2023-01-09, because I need to set the date range for input variable. So, the expected results missing  2023-01-05, 2023-01-06 and 2023-01-10.

Comment: Right , ccc should be included in 2023-01-10's total  as it has  a logout time of 2023-01-10 14:00:00.  I will see what i can do . By the way , I'm using MySQL 5.7, this means to adapt to your 5.0,  some features such as functions which were introduced later may have to be relinquished.

Comment: Finally did it. It sure took some time. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using MySQL 5.0, the convenient window functions which are introduced in 8.0 are out of questions. So we have to stick to the fundamental features. 
First of all, I would strongly suggest creating a temporary table named date_list which lists the complete dates between the minimum login date and the maximum logout date from the logged_log table. We only need to execute the complex query **ONCE** to make the temp table and it stays eligible for the rest of today. Otherwise, it wastes a lot of time if we put the code into the main query.(Trust me, the reponse time would be painstaking if we have to execute the complicated thing every time) Besides, by making a temp table it improves readability.

```
create temporary table date_list as
(select  selected_date as each_date from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between (select min(date(login_time)) from logged_log) and curdate()) 
;
-- let's test it
select * from date_list;

+------------+
| each_date  |
+------------+
| 2023-01-05 |
| 2023-01-06 |
| 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-08 |
| 2023-01-09 |
| 2023-01-10 |
+------------+
```

Next, we shall join the logged_log table with the date_list temporary table to get the ONLINE date for each username. The result will be worked upon in the final query. Note: Here I added the ORDER BY clause for better demonstration. But in the final query I shall remove it to save the filesort time.

```
select distinct username,each_date
from logged_log l
join
date_list d
on d.each_date between  date(login_time) and ifnull(date(logout_time),curdate())
order by username,each_date 
;
+----------+------------+
| username | each_date  |
+----------+------------+
| aaa      | 2023-01-06 |
| aaa      | 2023-01-08 |
| aaa      | 2023-01-09 |
| aaa      | 2023-01-10 |
| bbb      | 2023-01-06 |
| bbb      | 2023-01-07 |
| bbb      | 2023-01-09 |
| bbb      | 2023-01-10 |
| ccc      | 2023-01-07 |
| ccc      | 2023-01-09 |
| ccc      | 2023-01-10 |
| ddd      | 2023-01-05 |
| ddd      | 2023-01-06 |
| ddd      | 2023-01-07 |
| ddd      | 2023-01-08 |
| ddd      | 2023-01-09 |
| ddd      | 2023-01-10 |
+----------+------------+
```

At the final stage, we just need to do the aggregation using the result from the previous query.

```
select each_date as date,count(username) as total
from
(select distinct username,each_date
from logged_log l
join
date_list d
on d.each_date between  date(login_time) and ifnull(date(logout_time),curdate()) ) t
group by each_date
;
+------------+-------+
| date       | total |
+------------+-------+
| 2023-01-05 |     1 |
| 2023-01-06 |     3 |
| 2023-01-07 |     3 |
| 2023-01-08 |     2 |
| 2023-01-09 |     4 |
| 2023-01-10 |     4 |
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: To put the code into the main query would not be painstaking because the big O load the date_list temporary table too long time(more that 1 million rows), nobody will care the a little more time. Anyway, thank you, I appreciate your help very much.